# Trying to use background-image with a css variable in a Twig template

Tags: css, twig

So I have a problem. I want to use background-image with a css variable and, in my project, I use Twig to show articles one by one in a loop, selected from my database with an sql request. Every article has an relative link to the image in the database, so it can be seen on the website.

The thing is, I want to use the same image link that is in my database to the background of the article.

I tried using a css variable like this :

```css
div.liste {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        background-image: var(--image);
        animation: liste_appear .5s cubic-bezier(0.33, 1, 0.68, 1) 1 calc(var(--order) * 50ms) backwards;
        /*rest doesn't matter*/
}
```

and then, in the template, it looks like this

```html
{% for produit in produit %}
{% set compteur = compteur + 1 %}
<div class="liste" style="--order: {{ compteur }}; --image: {{ produit.image }}">
    <img src="{{ produit.image }}">
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

As you can see, I'm using another Twig variable that goes up everytime it loops and it works with the css (animations are getting delayed by 50ms times the number the variable "compteur" is on) but idk why it doesn't with the image variable...

And also, {{ produit.image }} works because it shows the image correctly.

If anyone has the answer, it'll be a pleasure to fix and thank the person !

Comment: The syntax for the `background-image` property is not `background-image: someImage.xyz`, it is `background-image: url(someImage.xyz)`.

Comment: FYI: `{% set compteur = compteur + 1 %}` is not needed as you can use the internal counter, `{{ loop.index }}` or `{{ loop.index0 }}`

Answer (score 0):

As [Darkbee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/446594/darkbee) says [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76225094/trying-to-use-background-image-with-a-css-variable-in-a-twig-template/76225169#comment134421493_76225094), just update your styles as per his twig fiddle. Didn't realize you scope css variables inline.

Comment: FYI: OP's code works just fine as long as he/she uses the proper CSS - [demo](https://fiddle.nette.org/twig/#92a4e778f6)

Comment: @DarkBee I generally declare variables for css at :root in the style sheet and didn't realize you could declare them inline. You taught me something today which will have a real effect on my work, thanks!